# get variable data from a class - swift

Tags: ios, swift, class

So, i have a file data.swift with some informations

```
class Data {

    var agen = […   ]
    var tours = […   ]
    var marseille = […   ]
    ……
}
```

In another viewcontroller, i m trying to get back a value from above with this.
I can get back a particular value with with command with success :

```
let entry = data.agen[indexPath.row]
```

It’s working but I would like set a variable in this command, I put this

```
    var passedValue:String!  
// passedValue coming from a segue from a previous VC
// passedValue could be "agen", "tours",”marseille” ...
    let entry = data.passedValue[indexPath.row]
```

But it's not working message error told me "data doesn't have a member named "passedValue"

How could i set properly the variable ?

Comment: data.passedValue only be useful if you have define Passedvalue in Data.swift! otherwise it show's error "data doesn't have a member named "passedValue"

Comment: passedValue will be one of the variable in Data (for example, "agen", "tours", "marseille", or ...) . So still good? i need to declare var passedValue on Data and what i need to declare in this variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about a slightly different syntax

```
class Data {

    var agen = ["A","B","C"]
    var tours = ["D","E"]
    var marseille = ["F","G","H"]

    subscript(index: String) -> [String]! {
        switch index {
            case "agen" : return agen
            case "tours" : return tours
            case "marseille" : return marseille
            default: return []
        }
    }
}

let key = "agen"
let data = Data()
print(data[key][1])
```

(maybe make a bit more error prof)

Answer (score 0):

Other solution is to create classes/structs for 'agen','tours', etc.
And set it in the Data object

```
class Data {

    var agen = [Agen(title), Agen(title2)]
    var tours = [Tour(title), Tour(title2)]
    …… }
```

Because, probably you want to show some info about the object in tableView later, so you could go like this:

```
title.text = tour.title
subtitle.text = tour.placeName
imageView.image = tour.photos[1]
```